# Facebook comment count per person

Tags: facebook, count, web, comments

Ok guys so I have this question, which facebook developers page doesn't answer. The only answer so far is on this page. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments which states that I can get the comment count on an entire URL. But I need it a little different way.

So I have a website with 10 different pages, each page has a separate Facebook comment widget attached to it. I want to make a gamified system and give badges to people who have commented at least 10 times (either on 1 or all different pages on the website).
Is this even possible? If yes, I would really appriciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, what you are trying to do is not allowed. You are not allowed to reward people for commenting. See 4.5 of the platform policy: https://developers.facebook.com/policy/

That being said, it´s not possible anyway. Facebook comments are black boxes, you don´t have access to them. The only (legal and possible) way to implement something like that is to create your own commenting system without Facebook.